# How can I get IP address of EC2 instance for Route53 in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I have three stacks created in **AWS CDK**:

- `shared-stack.ts` - Defines VPC shared Stack
- `routing-stack.ts` - Defines Route53 configuration
- `ec2-stack.ts` - Defines EC2 Instance

For Route53, I am trying to create `ARecord` that points to EC2 instance that was deployed in another stack. How can I make this happen? The IP address keeps changing as I deploy new and assigning the static IP address doesn't look like a good solution.

`routing-stack.ts`

```js
// Create route 53 zone
const vegafolioZone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, "MyZone", {
    zoneName: "mywebsite.com",
});

// A -> Point to EC2 instance IP address
new route53.ARecord(this, "ARecord", {
    zone: vegafolioZone,
    recordName: "app.mywebsite.com",
    target: //WHAT TO ADD HERE?
});
```

Comment: I don't use the CDK but from a straight Cloudformation perspective what you would want to do is export the target from your ec2-stack and then import it n your routing-stack.  
CDK documentation for output: [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnOutput.html)  
CDK documentation for import: [Fn:ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Fn.html#static-importwbrvaluesharedvaluetoimport)  
You might also need to check whether you would be better off creating an ELBv2 with your EC2 instance as a target and point Route53 at the ELB

Comment: @SteveG that would prevent any updates to the exported value (the question specifies the IP address keeps changing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get public DNS after creating AWS EC2 instance with CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104695/how-do-i-get-public-dns-after-creating-aws-ec2-instance-with-cdk)